# Can someone explain the "static" requirement for my code?

Tags: java

I am working through hackerrank and I felt pretty solid about my code, but it doesn't work.  Evidently, it has something to do with the way that I named the variables.  Ultimately, the goal was to output the area of a rectangle if the area is positive, and if not,

```
System.out.println("java.lang.Exception: Breadth and height must be positive")
```

This was my code:

```
int B = scan.nextInt();
int H = scan.nextInt();
scan.close();

 Boolean correct = (B > 0) || (H > 0);

    if(correct){
        int area=B*H;
        System.out.print(area);
    }
        else correct = false;
            System.out.println("java.lang.Exception: Breadth and height must be positive");
            scan.close();
```

This is the code that actually works:

```
private static int B;
private static int H;
private static boolean flag;

static {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    B = scan.nextInt();
    H = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();
    if (B <= 0 || H <= 0) {
        System.out.println("java.lang.Exception: Breadth and height must be positive");
        flag = false;
    } else {
        flag = true;}
```

I expected the input of negative integers to output the Breadth and height error, but instead it outputs

> 20java.lang.Exception: Breadth and height must be positive

Rather than using someone else's code (the second example), I would really like to fix my own code idea and understand the use of the static class better.

Comment: Your logic for `correct` says `B` *or* `H` must be positive, not `B` *and* `H`

Comment: Wow, don't rely upon that "code that actually works" for an indication of good Java programming. Also, don't close `System.in` (looks like a mistake in both your code and the "working" code). A correct answer, however, is if _both_ the breath and height are positive, so `correct =  b >0 && h > 0)`

Comment: no need for the `correct = false` statement, if it reaches that else clause that means correct is false anyway

Comment: I don't think your question has anything to do with the fact that the variables or function is static. Especially in Hackerrank this shouldn't be a problem since all code there is being run contained. as mentioned above your condition is wrong(should be &&) and `correct` will always be false if it isn't true because it is a boolean.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks the && was totally the problem, but now I ran into another issue.  Hackerrank is forcing me to code in a specific spot and I did not realize that it would not let me rewrite their code.                                                                 
             public class Solution {

Write your code here

public static void main(String[] args){
  if(flag){
   int area=B*H;
   System.out.print(area);
  }

Answer (score 2):

First, your condition should contain and AND not an OR. The input is correct if both the height and the width are positive.

Second, you have missed out braces after the else, so the `println` happens in all cases.

Also:

- You don't need to use `Boolean`, you can use `boolean`.
- You don't need to set `correct` to false after the else. In fact, you don't need it at all.
- Your indentation is wrong. It is much harder to get your code right if it is not indented correctly.
- Java variables should be lower case (`b` and `h`, not `B` and `H`).

Practice spending a bit more time reviewing your own code and learning how to debug it because these are very basic errors. It will help you a lot.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks the && was totally the problem, but now I ran into another issue.  Hackerrank is forcing me to code in a specific spot and I did not realize that it would not let me rewrite their code.                                                                 
             public class Solution {

Write your code here

public static void main(String[] args){
  if(flag){
   int area=B*H;
   System.out.print(area);
  }

Answer (score 0):

Your condition sould use && insteed of ||. Ans since you dont put {} to the else it only affect the  correct = false; and not the print.err

```
int B = scan.nextInt();
int H = scan.nextInt();
scan.close();

 Boolean correct = (B > 0) && (H > 0);

    if(correct){
        int area=B*H;
        System.out.println(area);
    } else
            System.err.println("java.lang.Exception: Breadth and height must be positive");
    scan.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code:

1. `(B > 0) || (H > 0)` This condition should use AND instead of OR: `(B > 0) && (H > 0)`
2. You forgot curly brackets at your "else" part of code.
3. Do not "throw exceptions" that way. It's hmm... weird.

This is what you want to do:

```
if (correct) {
    int area=B*H;
    System.out.print(area);
} else {
    correct = false; //as long as your're throwing exception in this block, this assignment is redundant
    scan.close();
    throw new Exception("Breadth and height must be positive");
}
```

P.S. Also to mention. You probably do not want to use a static block to put your code into. Use methods instead. Something like: `public int getSquare() {  }` and place your code inside.